# Mongodb reference in Node.JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reference

I am working on this side project and decided that while building the website I will use something new to learn along the way, so for my database solution I am using Mongo(mongoose). The idea is quite simple, I have 2 schemas - one holds players and another hold games:

```
var Player_Object = new Schema({
 "name": {
        type: String,
  },
  "words": {
        "to_guess":[String],
        "hint":[String]
  }
});

var gameIdSchema = new Schema({
  "name": {
        type: String,
        unique: true
  },
  "number_of_words": Number,
  "password": String,
  "creatingDate": Date,
  "players": [Player_Object],
  "teams": [{
        "team_number":Number,
        "team_name":String,
        "score" : 
              [{ "round_number" : Number,
                  "total_score" : Number,
                  "points"      :[Number]
              }],
        "players": [Player_Object]
  }]
});
```

As you can see, game schema has array of all players in the game, and array of teams that has also has array of players(that become assign later in the process). I was under the impression that Game schema references the player schema(since when I check in DB players in the player schema and in-game schema share same ID) this, however, is not the case.

Just to provide some background here is what I have when I create new game:

```
    let newGame = new Games({
    name: gameData.name,
    password: gameData.password,
    players: newPlayers,
    number_of_words: gameData.number_words,        
    teams: teams                     
    }); //new game created
```

Later in the code, players will edit their words, and when I check in DB i can see that in player schema words have been edited, but when I check the game schema - nothing was changed. I understand that this is due to lack of reference. Because when I update words, I only update them in Player schema.

My idea is this, when Players get updated, the Game Schema should see that this player now contains this words.

I looked through mongoDb notes and tried few ways but nothing seems to produce the results. So 2 questions: What is the proper way of referncing\defining schema here? And how would I update the Players so that they are updated everywhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is adding the player object in game schema and team schema. It is not a reference, it seems like it is a different object. So if you update a player, players in game and teams won't get updated. MongoDb does not have such functionality. Mongoose provides some thing but the mongoose library takes care of it.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

What you should do is store player Id's in the game and teams. Or store gameId and teamId in players (based on how you want to query and return result)

Every collection(table) in MongoDb is by itself and there is no way you can create a reference.